# How to resolve Errno 22 in datetime

Tags: python, python-datetime

receiving at Errno 22 Invalida argument error when passing in normal integer timestammp

I have tried adding a normal integer timestamp

```
final_change_int = dictionary["timestamp"]
print(final_change_int)
datetime.fromtimestamp(final_change_int)
```

Result

```
1551766560457
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-c6188e2f6967> in <module>
      1 final_change_int = dictionary["timestamp"]
      2 print(final_change_int)
----> 3 datetime.fromtimestamp(final_change_int)

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are doing great,

Unfortunately in this case it seems the value of the timestamp is wrong.

The date indicated by your timestamp is 12/7/51143 at 2:47:37. Based on the operating system it will not support such a date.

The best you can do in this case is to wrap the code in a `try...except`

And do what is needed in case of wrong timestamp.

N.B: In your case it seems that the timestamp must be divided by 1000, before to reach a correct date.

```
In [3]: datetime.fromtimestamp(1551766560457/1000)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 5, 7, 16, 0, 457000)
```

Have a lovely day,
My best regards.

G

Comment: @LM23 You are really welcome, I have added a possible solution to correct your timestamp. 

Have a lovely day.